# java finding height of binary tree recursively using 'for'

Tags: java, tree

I am trying to find a height of binary tree using for
plz help me out.
I have done it by using depth, but not this one
What should I add in questionmark?

```
public static int height2(Tree T, Node v) {
    if(T.isLeaf(v))
        return 0;

    int h = 0;
    for(?????) {  //need help!!!
        h = Math.max(height2(T,v.get_childLeft()),height2(T,v.get_childRight()));
    }

    return 1+h;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a for loop here? it seems to me that removing the for loop and letting `h = Math.max(...` should work fine.

Comment: u r right!! thx for advices!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you do not need to use `for`. It is binary three, each node has maximal two childs, so I think that line

```
    h = Math.max(height2(T,v.get_childLeft()),height2(T,v.get_childRight()));
```

may not be in loop. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The recursive approach towards calculating the height of only `childLeft` and `childRight`. We take maximum of two heights in case of binary tree. So using `for` for a single iteration statement makes no sense.

You can just return this and it willwork fine

`return 1+Math.max(height2(T,v.get_childLeft()),height2(T,v.get_childRight()));`

Cheers.